# Install worker service on Node and Angular old versions

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, service-worker

I'm trying to install a worker service inside an old Angular App. This app is running with `node v.12.22.1` and Angular 8.

When I try to install it as:

```
ng add @angular/pwa
```

It throws an error:

> The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v14.20,
> v16.13 or v18.10.

To solve that, I installed node 14.20 with node version manager as:

```
nvm install 14.20
```

Then:

```
nvm use 14.20
```

Now, when I try to run again the `ng add @angular/pwa` command it apparently going to install it but at the final throw an error:

> this.tree.readText is not a function

Complete log of install

> Your global Angular CLI version (15.1.5) is greater than your local
> version (8.3.14). The local Angular CLI version is used.
>
> To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch
> false". Installing packages for tooling via npm. npm WARN
> @angular/animations@8.2.14 requires a peer of @angular/core@8.2.14 but
> none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm
> WARN @angular/cdk@9.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^9.0.0 ||
> ^10.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies
> yourself. npm WARN @angular/cdk@9.1.2 requires a peer of
> @angular/common@^9.0.0 || ^10.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must
> install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
> @angular/platform-server@8.2.12 requires a peer of
> @angular/animations@8.2.12 but none is installed. You must install
> peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
> @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@0.7.0 requires a peer of
> @angular/core@^10.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer
> dependencies yourself. npm WARN @ngrx/effects@9.2.1 requires a peer of
> @angular/core@^9.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer
> dependencies yourself. npm WARN @ngrx/store@9.2.1 requires a peer of
> @angular/core@^9.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer
> dependencies yourself. npm WARN angular-font-awesome@3.1.2 requires a
> peer of font-awesome@^4.7.0 but none is installed. You must install
> peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN ng2-charts@2.3.0 requires a peer
> of chart.js@^2.7.3 but none is installed. You must install peer
> dependencies yourself.
>
> - @angular/pwa@14.0.0 added 43 packages from 73 contributors and audited 1642 packages in 15.123s
>
> 40 packages are looking for funding   run `npm fund` for details
>
> found 264 vulnerabilities (10 low, 93 moderate, 123 high, 38 critical)
> run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details Installed
> packages for tooling via npm.
> this.tree.readText is not a function

ng --version

```
 _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 8.3.14
Node: 14.20.1
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 8.2.12
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router

Package                                    Version
--------------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect                  0.803.25
@angular-devkit/build-angular              0.803.25
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer            0.803.25
@angular-devkit/build-webpack              0.803.25
@angular-devkit/core                       8.3.25
@angular-devkit/schematics                 8.3.14
@angular/animations                        8.2.14
@angular/cdk                               9.1.2
@angular/cli                               8.3.14
@angular/pwa                               14.0.0
@ngtools/webpack                           8.3.25
@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader   8.1.1
@schematics/angular                        8.3.14
@schematics/update                         0.803.14
rxjs                                       6.5.4
typescript                                 3.5.3
webpack                                    4.39.2
```

As you can see there, it has installed angular/pwa 14.0.0, so the version is too higher for my CLI version, which is 8.3.14. So I looking for a way to install an old version of PWA and you can do it as:

```
ng add @angular/pwa@(version)
```

The problem is I can not find the latest PWA version available for CLI 8.3

Answer (score 0):

The version history is available here - it looks like you would want to install 0.803.26, but just remember the syntax and examples are different with that version.  you may also not be able to do ng add and have to use yarn or npm to install it manually.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/pwa?activeTab=versions